# What can be an alternative to mongoose populate in native mongodb driver where my query may return multiple documents

Tags: reference

What can be an alternative to mongoose populate for mongodb driver where my query may return multiple documents and each document can have multiple children(max 5-6) stored in different collection. I want each document populated with children props.

fx.

a user has multiple orders and each order has many items(each order only stores the id of an item). Now I've a query to get orders between specific time period and that will reurn multiple orders and now i want these orders to be populated with item(fx item price, item size)

one potential solution could be get all orders and make 5-6(no. of items) additional query, which i assume to be a performance bottleneck

*Nodejs mongo driver